# How to remove the 3d effect of DataGrid rows

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

DataGrid rows have some kind of 3d visual effect by default. They look like shifted to the top-left corner.

[image]

How do I remove that effect and make the row look flat and not shifted?

I've tried changing BorderThickness of both CellStyle and RowStyle but that did not solve it.

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF0F0F0"/>
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Right"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Comment: Try DataGrid.GridLinesVisibility="None" on your datagrid.

Comment: It removes the 3d effect but the small padding from the right edge still remains. Any idea how to remove it as well?

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but I will add an answer for the sake of completeness.

As @Andy said in the comments, using `DataGrid.GridLinesVisibility="None"` works just fine.

```html
<DataGrid GridLinesVisibility="None">
    <!-- content -->
</DataGrid>
```

After reloading the view, the edges you mentioned in the comments will vanish. (They remain visible at the beginning only because the "Hot Reload" feature does not always update the spacing.)

Comment: Hi Felix, welcome to stack overflow and thank you for your answer! In the comments @yaugenka mentioned an issue with the padding - do you know how to solve this, in addition to the fix of removing the borders?